# Combining profiles in Maven to skip multiple categories of unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, maven, maven-profiles

I am having a problem trying to configure Maven to excluded some categories of unit tests based on multiple profiles.

I have two categories defined for unit testing: `SlowTest` for those unit tests that take a very long time to run, and `WindowsTest` for those unit tests that can only be executed within a Windows environment.

I have two profiles defined in my project's `pom.xml` file as follows:

```
<profiles>
  <!-- Exclude any tests in `SlowTest` category when profile 'skipSlowTests' is specified. -->
  <profile>
    <id>skipSlowTests</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <excludedGroups>SlowTest.class</excludedGroups>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>  

  <!-- Skip any tests in 'WindowsTest' category when not running on Windows. -->
  <profile>
    <id>skipWindowsTests</id>
    <activation>
      <os><family>!windows</family></os>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <excludedGroups>WindowsTest.class</excludedGroups>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>  

</profiles>
```

So for example when I want to run the tests and exclude any slow tests, I can execute `mvn -PskipSlowTests test`. And If I want to skip any Windows tests I can execute `mvn test` on a non-Windows OS (or explicitly specify `-PskipWindowsTests` on the command line).

The problem here is that when both the `skipSlowTests` and `skipWindowsTests` profiles are activated then only the Windows tests are skipped. The slow tests still run. When maven constructs the effective `pom.xml` file, it applies the `skipSlowTests` profile and configures `maven-surefire-plugin` to exclude the groups `SlowTest.class`. Then the `skipWindowsTests` profile is applied and this overwrites the excluded groups to be `WindowsTest.class`.

What I really want is the excluded groups to be `SlowTest.class,WindowsTest.class` when both profiles are activated, but I cannot figure out a way to do this.

There's no way that I can see in maven of appending a value to a property, e.g.

```
<properties>
  <excludedGroups>IgnoreTest.class</excludedGroups>
</properties>

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <excludedGroups>${excludedGroups}</excludedGroups>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

<profile>
  <id>skipSlowTests</id>
  <property>
    <excludedGroups>${excludedGroups},SlowTest.class</excludedGroups>
  </property>
  ...
</profile>

<profile>
  <i>skipWindowsTests</id>
  <property>
    <excludedGroups>${excludedGroups},WindowsTest.class</excludedGroups>
  </property>
  ...
</profile>
```

This `pom.xml` is broken, because there's recursion in assigning a value to the `excludedGroups` property.

And there's no way to set up a third profile (e.g. `skipSlowTestsAndWindowsTests`) that activates whenever both the `skipSlowTests` and `skipWindowsTests` are activated.

Any suggestions here? Maybe adding separate phases to `maven-surefire-plugin` (one for slow tests, one for windows tests, one for all others) and using profiles to determine which phases run?

**Edit #1**

I tried creating separate execution phases for the `maven-surefire-plugin` as follows:

```
<!-- By default, do not skip slow tests or windows tests -->
<properties>
  <skipSlowTests>false</skipSlowTests>
  <skipWindowsTests>false</skipWindowsTests>
</properties>

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <!-- Default execution will skip SlowTest and WindowsTest categories -->
    <execution>
      <id>default-test</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <excludedGroups>SlowTest,WindowsTest</excludedGroups>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <!-- Slow Test execution will run the slow tests only (if not skipped) -->
    <execution>
      <id>slow-test</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <skip>${skipSlowTests}</skip>
        <groups>SlowTest</groups>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <!-- Windows Test execution will run the windows tests only (if not skipped) -->
    <execution>
      <id>windows-test</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <skip>${skipWindowsTests}</skip>
        <groups>WindowsTest</groups>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>

<profiles>
  <!-- Skip slow tests when skipSlowTests profile enabled -->
  <profile>
    <id>skipSlowTests</id>
    <properties>
      <skipSlowTests>true</skipSlowTests>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  <!-- Skip windows tests when skipWindowsTests profile enabled -->
  <profile>
    <id>skipWindowsTests</id>
    <properties>
      <skipWindowsTests>true</skipWindowsTests>
    </properties>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

This configuration will run tests in three separate executions: the `default-test` execution will run every test except for slow tests and windows tests; the `slow-test` execution will run the slow tests only; and the `windows-test` execution will run the windows tests only. And if both the `skipSlowTests` and `skipWindowsTests` profiles are enabled, then both slow tests and windows tests will be skipped.

The problem here is when there is a test marked with both `SlowTest` and `WindowsTest` categories:

```
@Test @Category({SlowTest.class,WindowsTest.class})
public void slowWindowsTestCase() { ... }
```

When the `skipSlowTests` profile only is enabled, then the `windows-test` execution is still run, and since the `slowWindowsTestCase` method is marked as a windows test, it will be executed, even though we want to skip slow tests. Similarly, this test case will also be executed when the `skipWindowsTests` profile only is enabled. The only way to skip this test case is to specify both the `skipSlowTests` and `skipWindowsTests` profiles.

I tried modifying the executions as follows:

```
    <execution>
      <id>slow-test</id>
        ... 
        <groups>SlowTest</groups>
        <excludedGroups>WindowsTest</excludedGroups>
        ...
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>windows-test</id>
        ... 
        <groups>WindowsTest</groups>
        <excludedGroups>SlowTest</excludedGroups>
        ...
    </execution>
```

But now the `slowWindowsTestCase` method is never executed.

**Edit #2**

And even if I could get the test executions working correctly, I would need to add a dependency on `maven-surefire-plugin` so that the `SlowTest` and `WindowsTest` interfaces can be loaded during testing. I have put `maven-surefire-plugin` in the `pluginManagement` section of my parent POM, but any dependency defined for this plugin cannot have `test` scope. As a result, running a test outside of the module that defines the `SlowTest` and `WindowsTest` interfaces will not work. I can add a `test` scope dependency for the plugin in the profiles, but that will not cover the case when no profiles are active.

Comment: Interesting scenario. Do you agree that the problem is rooted into the syntax of `<excludedGroups>`: it should not be a type of `String` but rather an `Array` e.g. `<excludedGroups><excludedGroup>A</excludedGroup><excludedGroup>B</excludedGroup></excludedGroups>`. Now one can easily combine items into one list. You're welcome to [fire an issue for improvement](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE).

Answer (score 2):

You can make the default profile exclude all groups, and for each profile, you add one execution of the failsafe/surefire plugin including only one group.

Answer (score 1):

What about having each profile define a property `excludedGroups` and concatenate those into one property at the very start of POM execution?

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.9</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>excludedGroups</id>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <scripts>
            <script>
              <![CDATA[
              def groups = ""
              (project.activeProfiles).each{ profile -> groups += profile.properties.excludedGroups + "," }
              project.properties.excludedGroups = groups.substring(0, groups.length() - 1)
              ]]>
            </script>
          </scripts>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</build>

<profiles>
  <!-- Exclude any tests in `SlowTest` category when profile 'skipSlowTests' is specified. -->
  <profile>
    <id>skipSlowTests</id>
    <properties>
      <excludedGroups>SlowTest.class</activeByDefault>
    </properties>
  </profile>  

  <!-- Skip any tests in 'WindowsTest' category when not running on Windows. -->
  <profile>
    <id>skipWindowsTests</id>
    <activation>
      <os><family>!windows</family></os>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <excludedGroups>WindowsTest.class</excludedGroups>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now you can use `${excludedGroups}` as value for the surefire plugin configuration.